# C# how to give interface for dynamic object (don't know the properties in advance)

Tags: c#, .net

```
var databricksResponse = await _databricksLakehouseLogic.GetDatabricksDataBySQL(instanceId, query);
List<dynamic> records = new List<dynamic>();

if (databricksResponse?.Result != null)
{
    var arrayData = databricksResponse.Result[DataArray].ToList();

    List<ColumnSchema> columnsList = databricksResponse.Manifest.Schema.Columns.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.Count; i++)
    {
        dynamic record = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

        for (int j = 0; j < columnsList.Count; j++)
        {
            var row = arrayData[i].ToList();
            var column = columnsList[j];
            //var value = arrayData[i][j];
            record[column.Name] = row[j];
        }

        records.Add(record);
    }
}

return await Task.FromResult(records);
```

I have this code snippet, when I am trying to set `record[column.name]`, I am getting this error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type

How do I create an interface for an object whose keys are dynamically generated according to request?

Edit: i got the answer to use Dictionary if i don't know column names in advance

Comment: That completely contradicts the definitoion of an interface, which is some contract of an API to fulfill a specific expactation. If you cannot indicate what that contract looks like, how would you intend to apply to it in any way? However we have no clue what you consider to be "dynamic" here. If you have a static understanding of the structure of objects your dealing with, you should consider to create static types for them - e.g. create interfacea dn classes that implement them.

Comment: i have to create a response object based on column names i receive in request, how do i do that then?

Answer (score 1):

Since `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>` interface, you can cast your `ExpandoObject` to it and then use the standard dictionary methods like this

```
dynamic record = new ExpandoObject();
// Add a key/value pair
((IDictionary<string, object>)record).Add("ColumnName", row[j]);
// Now read the value
object value = ((IDictionary<string, object>)record)["ColumnName"];
Debug.WriteLine("record[ColumnName]: " + value);
```

Note that this code was intended to show the fact that an `ExpandoObject` always can be cast to a `Dictionary`. For your needs you probably had better not use an `ExpandoObject` but use a plain `Dictionary` object.

To enumerate the members, again we cast to `IDictionary` (example from MSDN):

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;
// Enumerate members
foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)employee)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Name: John Smith
Age: 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic variables allow you to refer to any property like this:

```cs
dynamic record = ...;
// This:
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"PropA: {record.PropA}");
```

But you don't have the property names during compilation time, so you need a dictionary-like object, not a dynamic object.

You can opt to change your logic to use an actual dictionary, or you may opt to use the [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0) class.